# Where can I find ready-to-use virtual machines?

Tags: virtualization, php

I'm new to virtualization, and I'm trying to create a couple of boxes for testing the software I develop (php) in diferent enviroments. I know php is portable, but sometimes it breaks because of case-sensitivity of filenames in linux and things like that.

I downloaded the vmw player but I don't know what to do next.

Should I download each SO .iso and create vms with that?

Or is there a better option, like a ready-to-use vm repository?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are open to trying a different virtualization software, I recommend http://www.virtualbox.org.

You could also find some great virtual appliances ready for download from http://virtualboximages.com/

Good luck!

Comment: link seem to be not working 16/10/2021

Answer (score 8):

The VMWare Virtual Appliance Marketplace has many pre-built appliances:
http://www.vmware.com/appliances/

Answer (score 5):

There are some in the answers to this question: [Pre-installed Linux for Web Developers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154457/pre-installed-linux-for-web-developers)

Then there's BitNami offering various ready-to-go VMs for various purposes: http://bitnami.org/

And the [VMWare Applicance market](http://www.vmware.com/appliances/directory/)

Answer (score 2):

VMPlayer does not allow you to create virtual machines, so installing from an ISO won't work. Here is a fairly comprehensive list of available Linux images. Some with LAMP setup as default
http://www.howtoforge.com/list-of-downloadable-vmware-images

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right then you are looking for something like [Turnkey](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/).